# ImportTextFile in Access Using VBA

Tags: vba, csv, dictionary, ms-access, import

I am stuck with the VBA function to import the CSV file into a table. It's a long code and I have tried to understand that. But I am unable to understand that whenever I import the data using VBA. It make changes to the structure of the destination table as well. I don't know either it's due to some saved import method or anything. I think there is an issue with this line:

```
 If blnProcessSource Then
    ' ImportTextFile(SpecNumber as Integer, SourceFileName as String)
    ImportTextFile intFileCount, dctFiles(intFileCount) 
    ' "dctFiles(intFileCount)" is returning the complete name and path to source file
    ReformatDates "tblTemp" & intSpecCounter
 End If
```

I have tried to search the "ImportTextFile" method but unable to find any answer to this function.

Comment: If blnProcessSource Then 
          ' ImportTextFile(SpecNumber as Integer, SourceFileName as String) 
           ImportTextFile intFileCount, dctFiles(intFileCount) 
          ' "dctFiles(intFileCount)" is returning the complete name and path to source file 
           ReformatDates "tblTemp" & intSpecCounter  
End If

Comment: That's obviously not a standard function, but something defined somewhere else. Usually, you can right-click the function name, then click definition, to see where the function is defined.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this.

```
DoCmd.TransferText _
        TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
        SpecificationName:="Generic", _
        TableName:="newTable", _
        FileName:="C:\your_path\your_file.txt", _
        HasFieldNames:=True
```

You can see some documentation here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transfertext